# String[] split of string[] array - ERROR

Tags: java, count

Here is my code :

```
String mensaje = "/server###33+32";

String[] msg = mensaje.split("###");
String[] numeros = null;


if (msg[1].contains("+")){
     numeros = msg[1].split("+");    <== ERROR HERE
}
```

And here is my exception error :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at juannmcc.servidor.Cliente.run(Cliente.java:49)
```

Need help cause I don't know how to do a split for a String[] array of a String[] array. 
Thanks.

Comment: escape your '+' with '\\+'...it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` has a special meaning in regex, so you have to escape it. Try this:

```
numeros = msg[1].split("\\+ ");
```

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex as its argument. `+` is a regex quantifier character used to match one or more characters so needs to be escaped to be evaluated literally

```
numeros = msg[1].split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 1):

the '+' character is a meta-character used to formulate regular expressions. If you wish to refer to it literally you need to escape it. The same goes with several other characters like `'.', '*', '[', ']'`, etc.

```
if (msg[1].contains("+")){
     numeros = msg[1].split("\\+");    // this should work
}
```

You might want to read [oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) on regular expressions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `+` in your regular expression. `+` in regular expression is used to denote 'one or more of the preceding element' and you have no preceding element, hence the error.

```
numeros = msg[1].split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tricky way if you do not want to use `\\`:

```
numeros = msg[1].split("[+]");
```